# Generate JSON object in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

For some reason I am not able to create JSON object in Groovy using JSONBuilder

Here is what I have but it comes back {}:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder()
    builder {
        name "Name"
        description "Description"
        type "schedule type"
        schedule {
          recurrenceType "one time"
          start "${startDateTime}"
          end "${endDateTime}"
        }
        scope {
          entities ["${applicationId}"]
          matches [
            {
              tags [
                {
                  key "key name"
                  context "some context"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Does anyone know a simple way to create JSON object with nested elements?

Comment: Why not something like `groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([name:'Name', description: 'Description', schedule:[recurrenceType:'one time']])`? The parameter is just a map with all the data.

Comment: @ernest_k I tried your suggestion. I think at this point, I tried any variation :/ my IDE complains if I add commas, like in your suggestion, so I didn't add them, yet it returns {} did you test your suggestion ? Does it work for you? return JsonOutput.toJson({name: "Name"
        description: "Description" ...}).toString()

Comment: What you have there is not what I suggested. I suggested a map parameter (`[... : ...]`, not `{}`). Yes, I tested it, it produced the string `{"name":"Name","description":"Description","schedule":{"recurrenceType":"one time"}}`

Comment: @ernest_k I good one. Almost there. How would I treat matches and tags that also need [ ] in the output? "matches": [
      {
        "tags": [
          {
               key "key name"
               context "some context"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
double them?

Comment: I'll add an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to find `JsonOutput` to be simpler to use for data that is already constructed. Yours would look like this:

```
groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(
   [name: "Name",
    description: "Description",
    type: "schedule type",
    schedule: [
        recurrenceType: "one time",
        start: "${startDateTime}",
        end: "${endDateTime}"
    ],
    scope: [
        entities: ["${applicationId}"],
        matches: [
            [
                tags: [
                    [
                        key: "key name",
                        context: "some context"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are creating a JSON from Groovy objects, then you can use; JsonOutput
2. And if you have several values to pass and create a JSON object, then you can use; JsonGenerator
3. Or you can use JsonBuilder or StreamingJsonBuilder

check the [groovy documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)